# Build VB6 project with GitHub actions

Tags: github, build, vb6, github-actions

I need to recompile VB6 code and then build the installer for an old VB6 project via GitHub actions.

Background : We have migrated this old VB6 project to a VSTO application. But still we have customers who use this VB6 solution. When building the installer, earlier we used Jenkins with a build machine that has VB6 installed on it. Now we no longer use Jenkins for builds and we use GitHub actions.

Even though the VB6 project is deprecated, due to some unavoidable reason, now we have to provide a new installer of the VB6 project with a bug fix. So I am looking for ways to build the vb6 application via GitHub actions.

In order to do this, we need to install VB6 in the Windows virtual machine provided by GitHub.
For installing Visual studio in the virtual machine, we can use below lines in the GitHub actions `.yml` file.

```
- name: Add msbuild to PATH
  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
```

But I didn't found similar action to install VB6. Turns out as VB6 is outdated, GitHub actions doesn't support it.

Does anybody have an idea how should I build the VB6 project with GitHub actions?
Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/1325

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you can integrate Github Actions with Azure DevOps (ex-Pipelines) but this might be your best option:

[How to setup CI with Azure Pipelines for VB6 projects on github.com](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?880049-RESOLVED-WIP-How-to-setup-CI-with-Azure-Pipelines-for-VB6-projects-on-github-com)

Comment: That is the second step. OP asked how to _install_ VB6 on the virtual machine via Github Actions. As your link states: _"Prerequisites: a (virtual) machine with licensed VB6 compiler (w/ SP6)"_

Comment: @HelO'Ween OP already said "Turns out as VB6 is outdated, GitHub actions doesn't support it" so they are aware of the limitations of GH Actions. They used to have a dedicated and licensed VB6 build server when thay used Jenkins and now they probably need similar solution as GH Action VM's cannot deal w/ licensed tools **at all**.